# How to change the value of a 'public static string

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public static String currentStudent = "";


public void login() {
  boolean studentLoggedOn = false;
  Student student = new Student();
  PC_Dialog dialog = new PC_Dialog("Enter Login Information", "Student ID, Password-", "OK");
  dialog.choice();

  String studentID = dialog.getField(1);
  String password = dialog.getField(2);

  student = (Student) projectSystem.studentFile.retrieve(studentID);

  if (studentID != null) {
     if (password.equals(student.password)) {
        currentStudent = studentID;
        studentLoggedOn = true;
        studentRun();
     }
  }

  if (!studentLoggedOn) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Either the user name or the password were incorrect");
     login();

}
   }
```

After all of that, the "`currentStudent = studentID;`" doesn't seem to have any effect on the currentStudent `String`?

Comment: are you sure `studentID` is not null and `password.equals(student.password)` ?

Comment: Having mutable static variables like this is disturbingly risky =/

Comment: This might work for one user...Hope you aren't planning on more than that currently!

Comment: and yes I'm pretty sure studentID is not null... password.equals(student.password) is only there because this is a login system.

Comment: I'm planning on hundreds of users :/

Comment: @nicholas, it's a fat-client app, so a static field for the current user will presumably work ok.

Comment: To help debug your issue, directly address currentStudent. So if the outer class, is say Outer, then make the line: Outer.currentStudent = studentID;

Comment: It's perfectly valid to change the value of a public static attribute :S. Any Runtime exceptions thrown?

Comment: I basically took away the 'public' so now it's just a 'static String'. but if I want to view the 'currentStudent' in another method (eg.  PC_Menu studentMenu = new PC_Menu("Hello " + currentStudent, "View points, View rewards, Your account, Logout");) it won't display it. It just has a blank space after the "hello" :/

Comment: otherwise it is working fine. I just need help on the above now? :)

Comment: studentID is probably blank, i.e. studentID="". Therefore, the code seems to have no effect. Check this. Note that null and "" are not the same.

Comment: I'm only a first year student so please mind me asking what the difference is?

Comment: @5luvyleevz "" == Empty bottle. Null == Bottle does not exist :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is incomplete, but if I had to guess, I'd say you have a reference to currentStudent somewhere else in your code.  Since strings are not mutable and the assignment operator also does not mutate objects, this reference would not change.

For example:

```
String one = "some string";
String two = one;
one = "another";
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
```

Will output

```
another
some string
```

Try reading up on Java references and string assignment.

Per the question author's request here's an example that accomplishes what I think he wants.

```
public class Session {
    private String currentUserId = null;
    public void setCurrentUserId( String id ) {
        currentUserId = id;
    }
    public String getCurrentUserId() {
        return currentUserId;
    }
    // Other session related information
    //... 
}
```

And use the Session class as follows.

```
public class MyApp  {
    private Session currentSession;
    public MyApp() {
        currentSession = new Session();
    }
    public void login() {
        //...
        if ( studentID != null ) {
            if ( password.equals(student.password) ) {
                currentSession.setCurrentUserId(studentID);
                //...
            }
        }
        //...
    }
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println(currentSession.getCurrentUserId());
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. you're completely correct. Is it possible for me to have the output:
another
another
(using your example to simplify things).
Thank you!

Comment: no.  Strings are immutable.  What you can do is create a class that has a string property and use setMyProperty("new string") and getMyProperty() to access the values.  In this way you avoid passing references to strings.  Get yourself a beginner Java book and all this will be explained... it's worth your time to read as you're going to run into a _lot_ more stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Either `currentStudent = studentID` does not get executed, or StudentID is something you are not expecting (empty string?). Either fire up a debugger or just insert a print statement(s) to see what happens:

```
     if (studentID != null) {
     if (password.equals(student.password)) {
        currentStudent = studentID;
        System.out.println ("StudentID is " + studentID);
        System.out.println ("CurrentID is " + currentStudent); // being paranoid here :-))
        studentLoggedOn = true;
        studentRun();
     }
   }
```

If you verify this shows as you'd expected, you can dig further

Comment: did Jason's answer solved your problem? If yes, please accept it so we also know this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site (question and answer on #20):
http://www.javacertifications.net/javacert/scjp1.5Mock.jsp

- you cannot change the value of as static String variable within a local method because of its immutable property.

Java 1.5